# How to Make Array Formula To Lookup Matching Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

As you'll see in my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dHHnlNKz3xtgzyRXdKCNjoz4RNb9bcDSwZKhkbfYOXw/edit#gid=170737397), I've already found the match between two columns (C and D) and put the results in E. So these values correspond to a value from C, but are in a different order.

Now I want the values from column A, but I need for the formula to match E's value to the correct row in column C first to get the correct corresponding subject in column A.

LMK if my description needs improvement, I just rewrote it about 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. There's no index function for array so you have to reconstruct a vlookup.

```
=filter(If(E2:E="","",vlookup(E2:E,{C:C,A:A},2,false)),not(isblank(A2:A)))
```

Comment: Happy to help, thanks for accepting. When you share the file, it makes it pretty easy. I've happened to be obsessed with Google Array functions the last six months. All kinds of usage with form results and automating spreadsheets. Hope your students find their books...

Comment: Actually @PGSystemTester I've discovered something wrong that I did! I had the formula for column E backwards...I fixed it so that it's giving me values that are in D that are in C, not the other way around...but now your formula is resulting in N/A and I'm at a loss how to correct it.

Comment: @CraigSeipWeinberg I think that fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, {C:C, A:A}, 2, )))
```